# Laptop cannot connect to the specific router

Tags: networking, 20.04, iwlwifi

My laptop cannot connect to the specific router (it works when I switch to Windows with the same machine, it works with other routers, other devices can connect to this router as well). What could be the issue? Where do I even begin?

Comment: Did you see your wlan? If yes try to log with `journalctl -f > ~/wireless.log` while you try to connect to your router.

Comment: @lucki1000 First message is just "Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com"

Comment: Can you run 'lspci' and type the response. It shows the information of your internal wifi card.

Comment: There's lots of stuff, one thing: Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165

Comment: You need to provide more detail in your question. You need to specify what version of windows connects, what situation doesn't connect -- it looks like maybe you are using Ubuntu 20.04? You should also indicate details about the router. Do you mean wifi? What type of router is it? Are you using 802.11a/b/c/g/n/ac/an/ax? How are you sure that the laptop is or is not connecting?

Comment: Open a terminal and type `iwlist chan`. Paste the output into your question. Also provide your router make and model.

Comment: When you say "it works with other routers", is that under Ubuntu?

Comment: Well... I guess you solved your problem, even if not giving feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a comment posted as answer, as it would be much less effective without markdown.

Did you set up that router?

I will name router R1 one to which you can connect,
and router R2 the problematic one.

This would take you some work, but without knowing the output of one or the other command, it is hard to tell which will reveal the problem.
Please post

1. When connected to R1, the output of

   1.1. Commands

```
  $ ip a
  $ ping -c 2 8.8.8.8
  $ netstat -nr | awk '$1 == "0.0.0.0"{print$2}'
  $ sudo lshw -class network
  $ lsusb
  $ lspci
  $ rfkill list all
  $ cat /var/log/dmesg | grep wifi
  $ cat /var/log/dmesg | grep network
  $ cat /var/log/dmesg | grep firmware
```

`netstat ...` gives  the local ip of your router.
Say, 192.168.0.1. Most likely that or similar.

2. When trying to connect to R2

   2.1. Same as above
3. What you see in a Windows browser when browsing http://192.168.0.1 (or the ip of your router)
4. What you see in an Ubuntu browser when browsing http://192.168.0.1 (or the ip of your router).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you miss drivers for wireless network card.
You can install it by following steps.

Download [Official Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 Drivers](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.30.14.0.tgz).

Unzip tarball file and copy `ucode files` in `/lib/firmware` of your ubuntu system.

```
tar xvf iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.30.14.0.tgz
cd iwlwifi-7265-ucode-25.30.14.0/ 
sudo cp *.ucode /lib/firmware
```

Comment: Strange... if this were the case, I guess the PC wouldn't connect to other routers under Ubuntu... at least I understood this is the case, although I am double checking.

Answer (score 0):

Do assign manually the ip address, netmask, gateway and dns manually of said wifi connection page in ubuntu wifi settings. Do assign ip address at a higher number so that it does not clash with any allotted by router to any other device.

edit: An Android device was having problem authenticating wifi, I had given ip address and others manually it immediately connected, no problems thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

just for a check ?

Did you remove : whoopsie ?

If not can you try this : sudo service whoopsie stop

Or

Optionally : "apt purge whoopsie"